# Howto use a derived pointer with template with constant pointer as argument

Tags: c++, templates

I want to define a template class that takes a global pointer as a template parameter that act like a *null-element*.
When the pointer to the null-element is of the same type the below code
work: `h<a *, &nullelem0> n0;`. However I would like to be able to work with a null-element that is derived from baseclass a. In that case
`h<a *, &nullelem1> n1;` fails:

```
62_temp.cpp:31:22: error: could not convert template argument ‘& nullelem1’ from ‘b*’ to ‘a*’
     h<a *, &nullelem1> n1;
```

which is understandable. Therefore I tried:

```
     h<a *, (a*)&nullelem1> n1;
```

which results in:

```
62_temp.cpp:31:26: error: ‘& nullelem1.b::<anonymous>’ is not a valid template argument of type ‘a*’ because ‘nullelem1.b::<anonymous>’ is not a variable
     h<a *, (a*)&nullelem1> n1;
```

*Is there a way to specify the template to accept a derived
class pointer when instantiating?*

```
class a {
public:
    a(int v) : v(v) {};
    int v;
};
class b : public a {
public:
    b(int v) : a(v) {};
};
class c : public a {
public:
    c(int v) : a(v) {};
};
a nullelem0(1);
b nullelem1(1);

template <typename _Tp, _Tp n>
class h
{
public:
    bool isnull(_Tp a) { return a == n; }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    h<a *, &nullelem0> n0;
    c p1(2);
    n0.isnull(&nullelem0);
    n0.isnull(&p1);

    /* this one fails: */
    h<a *, &nullelem1> n1;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing the following:

```
    template <typename _Tp, _Tp n, typename base= _Tp>
    class h
    {
    public:

        bool isnull(base a) { return a == n; }
    };
int main() {
...
c p1(2);
h<b *, &nullelem1, a*> n1;
    n1.isnull(&p1);
return 0;
}
```

Takes care of the non-convertability of the non-type template parameter yet still makes it comperable with any base pointer.